# Logical indexing using a vector

Tags: matlab, indexing, sum

I have vector `A = [2 3 1]` and matrix

```
B = [0 1 2;
     3 4 5;
     6 7 8];
```

I would like to be able to sum values in B using elements in A as logical indexers(start and end value).  More specifically, I would want my code to perform these actions :

`sum(B(1:1,1)`, `sum(B(1:2,2)`, `sum(B(1:3,3))` as to obtain the final vector C, such that

```
C = [3 12 2]
```

I have a large number of data, so I would like to avoid using for loops as they seem to slow down the code considerably.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How are you get ing those values for `C`?

Comment: @horchler: My answer fits, I guess it's what OP is after. I think your answer (as a whole) is better than mine, so I'll remove it if you update yours =) (Assuming I'm right)

Comment: @RobertP.: You're welcome, if you like. Is it that the OP has reversed the two indices? I'm just trying to get `3` out of `sum(B(1:2,2))`.

Comment: @horchler: I guess it should be `[sum(B(1:2,1), sum(B(1:3,2), sum(B(1:1,3))]`. (The column number has increments of 1, whereas the rows are indexed by `A`. Can that be right? (Also, I noticed *I* reversed the indices in my answer. Oops... Updated) Anyway: +1 for you, nice answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the info guys!  Was able to significantly reduce calculation time using your tips compared to the previous piece of "code" I had written!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
t = arrayfun(@(n)sum(B(1:A(n),n),1),1:numel(A))
t =
    11    15     6
```

For input:

```
A =
     2     3     1
B =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

I'm assuming you want the column numbers to be increasing, while the row number may vary.

Answer (score 2):

First, a correction. `A` can't be used directly for [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) because it is not a vector of logical (Boolean) values. What you are referring to is called [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511). This is where normal index values of 1 to the number of elements index the array as if it were a vector.

Here is one way you might solve your problem if `A` is actually `1:size(B,1)`:

```
B = [0 1 2;3 4 5;6 7 8];
C = sum(triu(B),1)
```

For a more general case a `for` loop may be pretty fast provided that you preallocate properly. But you can also use `arrayfun`, which is just a `for` loop in disguise (and even slower in many cases):

```
A = [2 3 1];
B = [0 1 2;3 4 5;6 7 8];
C = arrayfun(@(x)sum(B(1:x,x)),A)
```

None of this uses linear indexing because your `A` values describe how to index in to both the rows and columns of `B`. One can use `sub2ind` to easily convert to linear indices, but this can be cumbersome in usage, e.g.:

```
A = [2 3 1];
B = [0 1 2;3 4 5;6 7 8];
C = arrayfun(@(x)sum(B(sub2ind(size(B),1:x,x+zeros(1,x)))),A)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response.  I failed to mention that values in A are not necessarily growing.  For example, A could be [3 1 2] or [2 3 1].

Comment: @user3254790: Then isn't your example wrong? Your output seems to be for an `A = [1 2 3]`, not `[2 3 1]` as you use as input. Can you please update (if I'm not wrong)?

Comment: Yup, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative answer which uses [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to create a mask for the values that will be summed:

```
C = sum(B.*bsxfun(@le, (1:size(B,1)), A(:)).');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  C=cumsum(B); 
  C=C( sub2ind(size(B),A,1:size(B,1))  ),
```